# missing 1 required positional argument error in functions

Tags: python, function, tkinter, positional-argument

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *

window = Tk()
window.title('miles and km converter')
window.minsize('500', '300')
window.config(padx=20, pady=20)

input_user = Entry()
input_user.insert(END, string="0")
input_user.grid(row=0, column=1)

Label(text='is equal to').grid(row=1, column=0)

converted = Label(text='')
converted.grid(row=1, column=1)


def button_action(factor):
    saved_user_input = round(float(input_user.get()) * float(factor), 2)


mybutton = Button(text='calculate', command=button_action)
mybutton.grid(row=2, column=1)

from_point = Label(text='')
from_point.grid(row=0, column=2)

to_point = Label(text='')
to_point.grid(row=1, column=2)


def to_miles():
    from_point['text'] = 'km'
    to_point['text'] = 'miles'
    converted['text'] = button_action(factor=1)


def to_km():
    from_point['text'] = 'miles'
    to_point['text'] = 'km'
    converted['text'] = button_action(factor=2)


radio_state = IntVar()
radio_1 = Radiobutton(text="km to miles", value=1,
                      variable=radio_state, command=to_miles)
radio_2 = Radiobutton(text="miles to km", value=2,
                      variable=radio_state, command=to_km)
radio_1.grid(row=3, column=3)
radio_2.grid(row=3, column=4)

window.mainloop()
```

For some reason, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: button_action() missing 1 required positional argument: 'factor'
```

Why is this happening? I already declared the argument 'factor' in my button_action(). I also provided parameters for the function too. Does this have something to do with the placement of my code?

Comment: Callback of `command` option of `Button` expect no argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your `my_button` variable is calling `button_action` function. However, the function requires an argument(named factor in your case).

You can fix it using the lambda function.

```
mybutton = Button(text='calculate', command=lambda: button_action(input_user.get())
```

You will also need the input_user.get(). Since this is one of the ways to get the data from an entry widget in tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

In tkinter parameter `command` dont recive any argument. For use that you want you can 1) use global variable 2) use default value into function 3) use `functools.partial(function,default_value)`. Here is a sample where varible `factor` removed, becourse it is copy of `radio_state`. Also here used global variable, and you dont need call `button_action` with any parameter. Also here fix bug: on start dont set default mode and it calls errors.

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *

window = Tk()
window.title('miles and km converter')
window.minsize('500', '300')
window.config(padx=20, pady=20)

input_user = Entry()
input_user.insert(END, string="0")
input_user.grid(row=0, column=1)

Label(text='is equal to').grid(row=1, column=0)

converted = Label(text='')
converted.grid(row=1, column=1)

def button_action(): 
    saved_user_input = round(float(input_user.get()) * float(radio_state.get()), 2) #replace factor bcrse radio_state used now
    print(saved_user_input,radio_state.get()) #debug output

mybutton = Button(text='calculate', command=button_action)
mybutton.grid(row=2, column=1)

from_point = Label(text='')
from_point.grid(row=0, column=2)

to_point = Label(text='')
to_point.grid(row=1, column=2)


def to_miles():
    from_point['text'] = 'km'
    to_point['text'] = 'miles'
    radio_state.set(1) #set mode
    converted['text'] = button_action()


def to_km():
    from_point['text'] = 'miles'
    to_point['text'] = 'km'
    radio_state.set(2)
    converted['text'] = button_action()


radio_state = IntVar()
radio_state.set(1)#set default mode

radio_1 = Radiobutton(text="km to miles", value=1,
                      variable=radio_state, command=to_miles)
radio_2 = Radiobutton(text="miles to km", value=2,
                      variable=radio_state, command=to_km)
radio_1.grid(row=3, column=3)
radio_2.grid(row=3, column=4)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Did you forget to return `saved_user_input` inside `button_action()`? Or update `converted['text']` inside `button_action()` instead?

Comment: @acw1668, there are some errors, if i fix them all 7223이시윤, will lost some experience